# Function to sum a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible to make a function that sums the values of an array in C? And if so, how?

Here's what I've got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int a[][], int);

int main(void){
     int a[2][2]={{1,2}, {3,4}};
    printf("sum %d", sum(a,4));
    return 0;
}

int sum(int a[][], int n){
    int *p=a[0], sum=0;
    while(p){
        sum+=*p;
        p++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function), for knowing how to pass a multidimendionsal array to a function.

Comment: Can you tell us what's the problem with your solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes you can - i think this should work:

```
int sum(int **a, int n) {
    int *p = a[0], sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         sum+=*p;
         p++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int *a, int n);

int main(void){
     int a[2][2]={{1,2}, {3,4}};
    printf("sum %d", sum((int*)a, 4));
    return 0;
}

int sum(int *a, int n) {
    int *p = a, sum = 0;
    while(p != a + n) {
         sum += *p++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```